# Creating Transfer Orders gives Error - Company Not found

Tags: acumatica

In Release 5.3 While Creating Transfer Orders automatically (Replenishment to a Transfer Warehouse), the list gets generated but processing gives an error:

> Company ID : ### (Branch ID giving the BAccountID ) is not found for
>   Warehouse ### !

Is there any simple update way to resolve this in v5.3? I did not get this error in release v6.1

Comment: The issue I don't think it is in ver 5.3 - The problem is in the line [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<destinationSiteID>.IsRelatedTo<INSite.siteID>))]

Comment: Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Destination Warehouse value 346 Error: Customer '4784' cannot be found in the system. Please verify whether you have proper access rights to this object.

Comment: The issue was not inn Ver 5.3 or 6.1. The issue was because when you create Transfer Orders, Acumatica creates for the Branch a Transfer row in the database. Since there was some customization which was not enable to work for Sales Orders it failed and hence the error.